# Adding "Appendix" in front of "Figure" in cref

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, cleveref

I'm trying to create a list of appendix table/figures, which are formatted as: "Appendix Table/Figure #." I'm using the following code:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Appendix Figure}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Appendix Table}
\setcounter{figure}{0} 
\setcounter{table}{0}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Sources of Data}
\label{fig:appx_source}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{"Source"}
\end{figure}
```

However, when I use `\cref{fig:appx_source}` it seems like it outputs "Figure 1" instead of "Appendix Figure 1". Is there a way where I can make cref output "Appendix Figure 1"?

Comment: Will all `figure` and `table` environments be located in the appendix? Or might there be both a "Figure 1", in the body of the document, and an "Appendix Figure 1" in, well, the appendix? Please advise. A further question: Does your document employ the `hyperref` package? Finally, would you be willing to switch from "Appendix Figure 1" to "Figure A1", where `A` is the (alphabetical) "number" of the appendix section?

Answer (score 4):

*A comment up front*: I do not actually recommend that you implement the approach laid out in your query and pursued further in this answer. First, if your document employs the `hyperref` package as well and if your document has `figure` and `table` environments in both the main body and in the appendix, hyperlinks to figures and tables in the appendix won't come out right. Second, the cross-references will be quite long and quickly look clunky. (Instead, assuming the appendix sections are "numbered" `A`, `B`, etc, I'd recommend that you change the numbering system for `figure` and `table` environments from "1", "2", ... to "A.1", "A.2", ... via `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` and `\counterwithin{table}{section}` statements. That way, hyperlinks will be set correctly, and no cleveref-related adjustments are needed to begin with.)

---

You may achieve your formatting goal by making use of the aliasing mechanism described in section 6, "Overriding the cross-reference type", of the user guide of the `cleveref` package. Specifically, I would suggest that you provide two `\crefname` statements in the preamble, to define the alias labels for `figure` and `table` environments, and issue two `\crefalias` statements upon reaching the appendix material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
%\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{appfig}{Appendix Figure}{Appendix Figures}
\crefname{apptab}{Appendix Table}{Appendix Tables}

\begin{document} 
\section{Hello}  
Cross-references  to \cref{fig:source,fig:info,tab:there,tab:material}.

% A minimalist way of creating "labels":
\refstepcounter{figure} \label{fig:here}
\refstepcounter{table}  \label{tab:there}


\appendix
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Appendix Figure}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Appendix Table}
\setcounter{figure}{0} 
\setcounter{table}{0}
\crefalias{figure}{appfig}
\crefalias{table}{apptab}

\section{World}

\refstepcounter{figure} \label{fig:source}
\refstepcounter{figure} \label{fig:info}
\refstepcounter{table}  \label{tab:material}

Cross-references  to \cref{fig:here,fig:source}.
\end{document}
```